# Adding a Loop inside a loop

Tags: php, mysqli

Please am having an issue with loops, 
I have a loops of post content from a table, i want to add a loop of content from another table into the previous loop after two post. I succeeded in adding it, but it repeats the first loop and add into next loop.

[picture of what i got from the code bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDFCa.png)

below is my code sample

```
public function getTemplate() 
{

    $this->ci->load->library(['jobs']);

    if (! is_array($this->data)) 
    {
        $this->getFeed();
    }

    $storyList = '';
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($this->data as $storyId)
    {
        $count++;

        $this->ci->load->library('story');
        $this->ci->story->setId($storyId);
        if ($this->profileId > 0)
        {
            $this->ci->story->setProfileId($this->profileId);
        }

        $storyList .= $this->ci->story->getTemplate(); //template for content from first loop


        if ($count % 3 == 0) 
        {
            $this->ci->jobs->setLimit(2);
            foreach ($this->ci->jobs->getJobs() as $job)
            {
                $jobdata['list_job_title'] = $job['job_title'];
                $jobdata['list_job_code'] = $job['job_code'];
                $jobdata['list_job_company'] = $job['company_name'];
                $jobdata['list_job_slug'] = $job['job_slug'];
                $jobdata['list_job_created'] = $job['job_created'];
                $jobdata['list_job_country'] = $job['country_name'];
                $jobdata['list_job_state'] = $job['state_name'];
                $storyList .= $this->ci->load->view('home/jobs/feeds-job-each',$jobdata, true);// template for content from the second loop

            }
            unset($job);
        }





    }

    $storyData['story_timeline_id'] = $this->profileId;
    $storyData['story_list'] = $storyList;
    return $this->ci->load->view('home/feed/content',$storyData, true);
}
```

Comment: Not much we can do without the code...

Comment: Ok am going to add the code

Comment: @BizzyBob i added a code sample